# Code Ignitter SQL Model Fatal error: Call to a member function result() on a non-object

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter, frameworks

Oke guys, i have a little problem about my codeignitter website, the problem display like this.

**Fatal error:** Call to a member function result() on a non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\scbdnet\application\models\m_admin.php on line 88

The Code displayed like this :

**Model**

```
public function addUser()
    {
        $userid = $_POST['clientname'];
        $userpassword = md5(12345);
        $usernama = $_POST['completename'];
        $useremail = $_POST['email'];
        $usertelpon = $_POST['phone'];
        $usernodesktop = $_POST['desktop'];
        $usertypedesktop = $_POST['type'];
        $usercompany = $_POST['company'];
        $privilegeid = $_POST['level'];

        $query=$this->db->query("INSERT INTO table_user (userId, userPassword, userName, userEmail, userTelp, userNoDesktop, userTypeDesktop, userCompany, fkPrivilegeId, userStatus)
                                VALUES ('$userid','$userpassword','$usernama','$useremail','$usertelpon','$usernodesktop','$usertypedesktop','$usercompany','$privilegeid','1');");
        return $query->result(); //LINE 88
    }
```

**Controller**

```
public function adduser_to_db(){
    $this->load->model('m_admin');
    $this->m_admin->addUser();
    redirect('admin/user');
  }
```

**Views**

```
    <form action="<?php echo base_url();?>admin/adduser_to_db" method="POST" name="adduser" id="adduser">
       <div class="row form-row">
          <div class="col-md-12">
             <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="New Username" name="clientname">
             <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Complete Name" name="completename">
             <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" name="email">
             <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Phone Ext." name="phone">
             <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Desktop no." name="desktop">
             <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Desktop type" name="type">
             <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Company" name="company">
             <select id="level" style="width:100%" name="level">
              <?php foreach($priv_list as $list){ ?>
              <option value="<?php echo $list->privilegeId?>"><?php echo $list->privilegeStatus?></option><?php }?>

             </select>
            </div>
           </div>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="adduser" id="adduser" value="adduser">Save changes</button>
        </div>
   </form>
```

Any idea guys?

Comment: can you please show your model class initialization code

Comment: If you want to make sure your record is inserted you can use $this->db->affected_rows()

Comment: @nana.chorage All the record inserted successfully.

Comment: You can't use $query->result(); its only for Select statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$query->result(); does not work here
```

try like this

```
  public function addUser()
        {
            $userid = $_POST['clientname'];
            $userpassword = md5(12345);
            $usernama = $_POST['completename'];
            $useremail = $_POST['email'];
            $usertelpon = $_POST['phone'];
            $usernodesktop = $_POST['desktop'];
            $usertypedesktop = $_POST['type'];
            $usercompany = $_POST['company'];
            $privilegeid = $_POST['level'];

            $query=$this->db->query("INSERT INTO table_user (userId, userPassword, userName, userEmail, userTelp, userNoDesktop, userTypeDesktop, userCompany, fkPrivilegeId, userStatus)
                                    VALUES ('$userid','$userpassword','$usernama','$useremail','$usertelpon','$usernodesktop','$usertypedesktop','$usercompany','$privilegeid','1');");
           if($query){
                     return true;
                    }else{
                        return flase;
                     }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `$query->result();` in insert query as it `does not populate any result`. It works only on select queries.

but if you want to get last insert id then you can use `insert_id()` as

```
$insertid = $this->db->insert_id();
```

You can use [active record](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html#insert) to insert data in table

```
$data = array(
   'userId' => $_POST['clientname'] ,
   'userPassword' => md5(12345) ,
   'userName' => $_POST['completename'],
   ..... for all your column data
);
//then insert into table 
$this->db->insert('table_user ', $data);
```

Comment: this one was supposed to be the accepted answer according to me :/